# Django templatetags: objects inside filter

Tags: python, django, templatetags

Let say, I want to create a simply templatetags for dynamic counter, and how can I inject an example the `{{ request.user }}` inside value of `author` : `{{ 'blog.model.Post'|counter:"{'author':'...?'}" }}`?

In my bad idea, `{{ 'blog.model.Post'|counter:"{'author':'request.user'}" }}`, but of course it should return string of `'request.user'` but not actual object.

```
import ast
from django import template
from django.utils.module_loading import import_string

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def counter(model_name, filter=None):
    """
    by all objects:
        {{ 'yourapp.model.ClassName'|counter }}

    by filter objects:
        {{ 'yourapp.model.ClassName'|counter:"{'field_name':'value'}" }}
        > example:
        {{ 'blog.model.Post'|counter:"{'author':'...?'}" }}
    """
    model = import_string(model_name)
    if filter is not None:
        filter_dict = ast.literal_eval(filter)
        return model.objects.filter(**filter_dict).count()
    return model.objects.count()
```

> **As a note;** why I'm not handle it into `models.py` or `views.py`?
>   Because I'm using this method to provide my plugin that focused on templatetags only.

Comment: You wouldn't do this at all; it's far too much logic for a template. Just the fact that you're having to do `literal_eval` should be a red flag.

Comment: can you suggest me an idea to do it?

Comment: This belongs in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the best approach on this situation is not a templatetag, is a @property:

```
class foo(models.Model):
    foo_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    @property
    def get_foo_count(self):
        ...some code ...
        return 1
```

You can call propertys from templates.

If you still want to use templatetags:

on templatetag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_foo_count(foo):
        return 1
```

on template:

```
{% load foo_templatetags %}
{% get_foo_count foo as foo_count %}

{{ foo_count }}
```

Comment: I know it, I just provide this for [my plugin](https://github.com/agusmakmun/common-tags/blob/master/common/templatetags/common_tags.py#L103-L119) not for my project.. so, this why I created a dynamic counter...